# Undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume' with QT

Tags: c++, qt

When trying to switch to gcc 4.6.2 in qt (setting it in a toolchain) I'm getting the following error:

```
c:\ndk_buildrepos\qt-desktop\src\winmain\qtmain_win.cpp:93: error: undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
```

Any idea how to fix it?

```
//.pro
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

Comment: Are you maybe linking with gcc instead of g++? please show at least the linker line.

Comment: @PlasmaHH where can I get the linker line from?

Comment: When you switched, did you clean out all of the old .o files so they will be rebuilt with the new compiler?

Comment: Could it be that you link to libraries compiled with an older version of g++? In that case, I'd check whether there was an ABI change in exception handling between your previous g++ version and 4.6.2.

Comment: @celtschk there is almost certainly linking to a libraries build with older version of gcc. Qt was build with gcc 4.4, I'm trying to use gcc 4.6.2

Comment: @all I found the problem: The ver of gcc (TDM build) installed must neither be dw2 nor sjlj, mingw the top one should be installed instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I download and installed a Qt library alone (i didn't download the whole SDK)
2. I Wrote a simple Hello Qt window..
3. I link it with my Dev-Cpp (since Dev-Cpp is using MinGW as well) mine version actually is 3.4.x not 4.4.x...
4. I compile it the Qt way using **qmake** .. etc..
5. I got an error you have experienced as well..

... "_Unwind_Resume ..." ...

**My Solution (simple, very simple)**

1. Run the Qt X.X.X. (Build Debug Libraries) or..
2. Run the **qtvars.bat** (depending on the version of Qt you are using) mine is 4.8.0..
3. 1 and 2 are the same thing..

I did a hit of **make** again.. it runs..:)

p.s. it solves my problem.:) I hope it can solve yours too.

Answer (score 6):

Undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume` are caused by compiling with a GCC with a different stack unwinding method from that used by the library you're trying to link with.

As stated above, the solution is to rebuild the library with the same compiler.  Just noting the cause for future google visitors.